# How to save an i2c address in python

Tags: python, for-loop, raspberry-pi, i2c

hi i found this code in internet to detect i2c address in python on raspberry pi 3, it works well the result im getting is: 10: 10 11 but i want to save each result in a different variable for example x=10 y=11, the first 10 doesnt matters, any  idea? im aprreciate your answer!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import subprocess
import re

p = subprocess.Popen(['i2cdetect', '-y','1'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)

for i in range(0,9):
  line = str(p.stdout.readline())

  for match in re.finditer("[0-9][0-9]:.*[0-9][0-9]", line):
    print (match.group())
```

Comment: You can use a dictionary, if you are sure those values will  be the same.

Comment: better use dictionary - like `results["x"] = 10`, `results["y"] = 11` or keep on list `results = [10, 11]`. What is the problem ? Don't you know how to `split()` text into words and convert words into `int()` numbers ?

Comment: You should definitely put the full output of i2cdetect as well so people can give you better suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't know how to split text into words and convert to numbers

```
text = "10: 10 11"

words = text.split(" ") # ["10:", "10", "11"]
x = int(words[1])
y = int(words[2])

print(x, y)

# 10 11
```

Comment: Thanks i'm new in python i'm appreciate your answer, works well